# mongoose findOne with multiple paramters does not work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My schema is as shown below:

itemLike.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const itemLike = new Schema({
    item_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'items', index: true },
    no_of_likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }]
}, { versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('item_like', itemLike);
```

My query is as shown below:

```
itemLike.findOne({ 'item_id': itemData.item_id, 'user': userInfo }).then((info) => {
                    if (!info) {
                        let newItem = new itemLike();
                        newItem.no_of_likes = 1;
                        newItem.users.push(userInfo);
                        newItem.save().then((likeInfo) => {
                            res.json({
                                status: '200',
                                message: 'Thanks for appreciating our product',
                                data: likeInfo
                            });
                        }).catch((err) => {
                            console.log("hh " + err);
                            res.json({
                                status: '500',
                                message: 'Oops,something went wrong'
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            status: '200',
                            message: 'you have already liked the product'
                        });
                    }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("ll " + err);
                    res.json({
                        status: '500',
                        message: 'Oops,something went wrong'
                    });
                });
```

Here suppose my response is as shown below:

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "Thanks for appreciating our product",
    "data": {
        "_id": "5990dd8e669a041fec3aecb9",
        "users": [
            "591325c6b685bc165313a8ff",
            "591325c6b685bc165313a8ef"
        ],
        "no_of_likes": 1
    }
}
```

now suppose when I put findOne query with `item_id: 5990dd8e669a041fec3aecb9` and `users:591325c6b685bc165313a8ef`, it should give me the exact document. But for this case findOne is not able to find documet, I think as `users` field is an ref-array, it is not able to look at both the parameters. So how can I achieve this functionality ?

Comment: It should be `users`, not `user` (single).

Comment: Yes, I changed the `users` , but problem still persists. For that I have updated me question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `itemData.item_id` and `userinfo` are both IDs, then you would do

```
 itemLike.findOne({ 
     _id: itemData.item_id,
     users: {
         $in: [userInfo]
     }
 }).then(...).catch(...);
```

You use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) since `users` is an array.

**Edit**

The query is not working because you are looking for `item_id` but nowhere in your code do you store `item_id`.

Looking at your response, however, you'll see that the two values you are looking for are stored in `_id` and `users`. Therefore use `_id` and `users` in your query as shown above.

Comment: $ in is not able able to find out userInfo in `users` array